# How to edit a custom theme?

Tags: posts, dropdown

I am new to WordPress and I started working on a project. I have found a customized theme which I have to change. I have to create a dropdown menu in the navigation bar that shows some subcategories and the 3 latest posts. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on your theme. If you're not sure how to do it, you'll probably need to hire someone to assist you.

Comment: Pat J is totally right, this has a lot of things that can be different in a lot of themes, but here is something that maybe can help you without any codding, if you know where is where you want to put that drop down menu, for example a page, maybe the page section has an editor like elementor, if that is the case, maybe in elementor you have an option of dropdown menu that you can use. another option, for example if is a sidebar section, maybe on the side bar tab, you can add a dropdown to that section.

Comment: No, it is in the main navbar that is shown on every page and also is not using elementor. I am using the CSS hero plugin to change some parts of the design but this is different and I think it should be done via code. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.